# Error on the s of clearcontents on the same line

Tags: excel, vba

> VB runtime-error 1004 : "We can't do that to merged cells"

How can I solve this issue?

```
Sub Cont_New()
  With Sheet1

    .Range("R33").Value = True 'Contact Load
    .Range("R32").Value = True 'New Contact to True
    .Range("D7,D9,D11").ClearContents
    .Shapes("ExistContGrp").Visible = msoFalse
    .Shapes("NewContGrp").Visible = msoTrue
    .Range("R33").Value = False 'COntact Load to False
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which cells are merged?

Comment: Perhaps you should delete this question, as it seems like you've got it answered elsewhere.