# How to apply code, to merged cells, that produces Runtime-Error :"We can't do that to merged cells."

Tags: excel, vba

This is the design I want to use to provide data to a table below and vice-versa.

[image]

```
Sub Cont_New()
With Sheet1
 .Range("R33").Value = True 'Contact Load
 .Range("R32").Value = True 'New Contact to True
 .Range("D7,D9,D11,D13,D15,D17,D19,D27").ClearContents
 .Shapes("ExistContGrp").Visible = msoFalse
 .Shapes("NewContGrp").Visible = msoTrue
 .Range("R33").Value = False 'COntact Load to False
End With
End Sub
```

How can I solve this issue with the merged cells?

> Runtime-Error :"We can't do that to merged cells."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error on the s of clearcontents on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473466/error-on-the-s-of-clearcontents-on-the-same-line)

Comment: No, it didn't solve the problem and further the question itself wasn't complete.

Comment: Sorry din;t get what to put in Value=" "

Comment: no do not use `" "`. Use `""`. No space between the double quotes. I have posted an answer. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a **MIX** of both kind of cells, either use

```
Range("D7,D9,D11,D13,D15,D17,D19,D27").Value=""
'OR
Range("D7,D9,D11,D13,D15,D17,D19,D27").Value = vbNullString
```

OR loop though the range and check if the cell is merged. If it is merged then use `.MergeArea.ClearContents` else use `.ClearContents` as shown below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("D7,D9,D11,D13,D15,D17,D19,D27")

    For Each aCell In rng
        If aCell.MergeCells Then
            aCell.MergeArea.ClearContents
        Else
            aCell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next aCell
End Sub
```